# failure of 'or' operator in python

Tags: python

```
import random 

num_list = []
for i in range(0, 100 + 1):
    num_list.append(i)

for i in range(50):
    output = random.sample(num_list, 3)
    print(output)
    if 0 or 100 in output:
        print('yes')
```

I am trying to print a list of 3 numbers in random (0 to 100) for 50 times. When 0 **or** 100 is on the list, I want to print 'yes' in the console. However, when I run the code, only when the list has 100 shows 'yes', but not in the situations when 0 is on the list. What causes the problem? Did I use the 'or' operator mistakenly?

Comment: Replace it with `if 0 in output or 100 in output`.

Answer (score 0):

`if 0 or 100 in output:` is parsed as

```
if
  (0)
  or
  (100 in output)
```

and `0` is always falsy.

You'll want `if 0 in output or 100 in output`, i.e.

```
if
  (0 in output)
  or
  (100 in output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
if 0 or 100 in output:
```

is interpreted as

```
if (0) or (100 in output):
```

So the condition is true only if 100 is present in `output`. To fix this you need

```
if 0 in output or 100 in output:
```